# What does the third line in this code mean in Python?

Tags: python, list

```
list1 = input("list aval ra vared kon:   ").split()
list2 = input("list dovom ra vared kon:   ").split()

#I do not understand the following line
list1 [ : 0] = list2

print("javab is :  " , list1)
```

Comment: It's the same thing as `list1 = list2 + list1`, but written by someone who thinks they're really clever.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Technically, it's slightly different, because the first one modifies the existing `list1` and the second one replaces it with a new list.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code: `list1 [ : 0] = list2` adds all the value of `list2` directly into `list1` The values added are before the actual values of list1.

For Instance, take this example,

```py
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
# Case 1
list1 [:0] = list2 # list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# Case 2
list1 [:1] = list2 # list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

#Case 3
list1 [:2] = list2 # list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

The syntax `list[start:stop]` is used to slice lists into smaller parts. For more information, see this StackOverflow Post: [Understanding slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slicing)

The `[:0]` shows that all the elements in `list2` must be inserted into `list1` before the 0th element(First Item in `list1`)

Had you inserted `[:1]`, the element before in `list1` ('a' -> list1[0]) would have been replaced with the values present in `list2`

Hope this helps.